# How does Prigozhin justify the war in Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, wagner-pmc

The Kremlin’s narrative for the war against Ukraine has essentially been: the West has been trying to increase their dominance in the region, Zelenskyy is backed by the West, and Ukraine in its then state presented a threat to Russia’s security (there were some claims that a Ukrainian attack against Russia was imminent, but I am not sure whether authorities ever officially made such a claim). Thus, as far as the Kremlin is concerned, the war was necessary for Russia’s security.

Now Prigozhin has essentially denied such a threat existed, and claimed other motives played a role. On the other hand, he has in the past taken an even more aggressive stance towards Ukraine. Objectively, if both statements were to reflect his actual position, they would be at odds with each other, unless he were to support whatever other motives there may have been at play (financial gain for Russian oligarchs was one of the things he mentioned).

Firstly, are there any indicators by which one could assess how accurately these two statements reflect his actual beliefs? Has he given any indication regarding his own motivation for supporting the war against Ukraine?

Comment: Related [Who is behind Prigozhin?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80031/who-is-behind-yevgeny-prigozhin)

Comment: Has he said he agrees the war should have been launched, or has his view been “we’re at war and so should fight it aggressively?” There’s no inherent contradiction in thinking that while you disagree with a decision to go to war, that decision has already been made and you will support the war effort to the best of your ability.

Comment: *"a Ukrainian attack against Russia was imminent"* - I don't think that's the most likely argument, if "attack" means something military in nature. In the near-term, the continuation of political agitation and the promotion of separatism and pro-Western (as distinct from pro-Russian) politics, as well as defensive fortifications which increase the cost of Russia checking these Western-led activities using military force (i.e. weakening the political influence of the Russian military), would be the most likely consequences which Russia feared.

Comment: @Steve there was a claim about planned attack against Donetsk and Lugansk, which were not considered (by Russia) as apart of Russia then. In this sense, the OP misrepresents facts.

Comment: I have indeed heard the claim that, had Russia not attacked, they would have been under attack themselves. However, I cannot tell to what extent the Kremlin has actually made claims of an impending attack on Russian territory.  I’ll rephrase the question.

Comment: Voting not to close - It is clear that even before the coup attempt, Prigožin was, and continues to be, a political player in Russia. Thus, an analysis of his statements on the political situation in Ukraine is well within the rules of Po.SE.

Comment: Voting to keep open. The primary purpose of this question appears to be to learn about Prigozhin, who is a political figure in Russia, not discredit him. The Q is a good-faith, well-researched effort to learn more about politics in Russia.

Comment: He's a mercenary. He'll kill anyone if he gets paid for it, probably.

Answer (score 6):

**He does not.**

> война была нужна лишь для того, чтобы кучка тварей просто поторжествовала и попиарилась

> the war was needed only so that a bunch of beasts would just
> triumph and improve their PR

Here complex to translate but maybe *the war was needed only so that a bunch of beasts just triumphed and promoted themselves*. This seems
not open to more than one interpretation.

He thinks that there were no immediate plans from the side of Ukraine to invade Russia [(source)](https://meduza.io/feature/2023/06/23/rossiyskaya-armiya-otstupaet-minoborony-obmanyvaet-putina-ukraina-i-nato-ne-sobiralis-napadat-na-rossiyu). He is not on the Western side but likely thinks that the invasion has been not the right action to take at the time.

This can also be confirmed by his later statements after the mutiny ([source](https://%20https://meduza.io/feature/2023/07/19/to-chto-proishodit-na-fronte-eto-pozor-v-kotorom-nam-ne-nuzhno-uchastvovat)):

> То, что происходит на фронте, это позор, в котором нам не нужно участвовать

> What's going on at the front is a disgrace that we don't need to participate in

Comment: Only the last word can´t be directly translated, so I rephrased.

Comment: So far, so good, but this doesn’t explain why he is then advocating a fiercer stance on Ukraine. If the war was not necessary, then why direct even more resources at it, rather than call the whole thing off? Sure there may be reasons for doing so: maybe he’s always wanted to conquer the place, regardless of whether they were a threat or not. Or, as others have stated, the war was not needed but it was started anyway, so now the only option is to fight and win it. The question is – what is Prigožin’s rationale for supporting the war effort? Has he given any indication?

Comment: @user149408: Since the quotes being discussed pre-date his brief rebellion, a likely answer is that he wanted his mercenary company to get more business.

Comment: @user149408, rationale? He's a populist (or playing such) that can put Trump to shame. He offers everything to everyone. He called for total mobilisation and pulling off in the same speech. He's also very protective of his business, which incidentally doesn't preclude him from flushing it down the drain, in his wisdom.

Comment: The problem with that claim is that Prigozhin is himself seen as a prominent "triumphing beast", and "oligarch". Not judging, just pointing out.

Comment: This is fully consistent and just honest - he runs a mercenary business getting contracts from the state. Of course he is the oligarch and benefits from war.

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to leave this as a comment, but the volume did not fit. As others have already replied, apparently Prigozhin provided no justification for the war from his side (more on that at the end of the answer). Hence I am mostly trying to address the point about whether there may be a consistence in his views.

I'm not an expert on Prigozhin's statements, but I have noticed that several time before the coup he has addressed Ukrainiand (and Zelensky in particular) directly. Speaking about the situation in Bakhmut recently he mentioned that "Vladimir Oleksandrovich" is cunning or (sic!) may not have the most correct information about what's happening.

> «Бахмут взят полностью. Поэтому Владимир Александрович лукавит. Либо он не в курсе, что происходит на земле»

Translation:

> "Bakhmut has been taken completely. Therefore, Vladimir Alexandrovich
> is lying. Or he doesn't know what's going on on earth."

This seemed to be a sharp contrast to the rhetoric of the rest of the command from the side of Russia, who were and are mostly talking about the western role in the conflict, apparently stressing their belief that decisions are not made in Ukraine. So despite being deeply involved in the war on the military side, his ideology might have been different from the official one for quite some time and if this is the case I see no inconsistency with his previous claims such as the one above, and those he made before the start of the coup.

Let me repeat myself again: I was not closely following what he was saying, so maybe there are examples of his statements that do not fit what I wrote above. One should keep in mind though, that anyone in his role even if they had a slightly different opinion would not openly talk about that due to a very likely retribution. As a result, if you really want to understand what "his actual beliefs" you should not read his statements as absolute ones, but look at their deviation from the official rhetoric.

For this reason, that was such a big surprise to me that he openly mentioned lack of reasons for the start of the war. Even calling this a war is a crime in Russia, let along saying there were no reasons for it. This statement alone could have bought him a long stay in prison. Actually it might have had a much bigger effect if he did not go for the coup after, since the latter stole the news. After Prigozhin has declared a traitor his words could be simply disregarded. If not that, Russian government would have to deal with a military commander with a lot of media influence in Russia, who is officially praised as a kind of a hero, and who is also saying that the government outright had no reasons to start the war. Instead now his words on this topic seem to not be addressed at all.

Comment: "Even calling this a war is a crime in Russia" is mostly FUD.

Comment: How FUD? https://www.npr.org/2022/03/05/1084729579/russian-law-bans-journalists-from-calling-ukraine-conflict-a-war-or-an-invasion

Comment: @alamar can’t comment on its practice but that’s the official law

Comment: The law does not say anything of that sort. "Russian officials[who?] assert that" is exactly the weasel-worded FUD I'm talking about.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the statement by Prigozhin:

> "The Council of Commanders of the Wagner PMCs has made a decision: the
> evil that the country's military leadership is carrying must be
> stopped. They neglect the lives of soldiers, they have forgotten the
> word "justice", and we will return it. Therefore, those who destroyed
> our guys today, and tens of thousands of lives of Russian soldiers,
> will be punished. I ask no one to resist...We will deal with those who
> are destroying Russian soldiers **and return to the front**,"
> Prigozhin said.

As can be seen from the bold part, he is not opposing the military operation.

Comment: Source for that statement? I found [a tweet](https://twitter.com/WarFrontline/status/1672315770355720212) which cites a longer passage. Right after your quote it continues with (there's more): "After we finished what we started, we will return to the frontline to protect our motherland." Dated just before his going into Russia, it's not clear which parts of your quote are referring to the Ukrainians or the Russian military leadership.